# Depending on PyAudio

Tags: python, build, setuptools, pyaudio

Im trying to build a [python package](https://github.com/Pizza989/voice_commands) using setup.cfg, pyproject.toml the build module and a setuptools build backend (this is ridiculous). This Package depends on PyAudio which can not be install via pip though if the required portaudio19-dev package, which i cant find on my system (open suse tumbleweed), is not installed. PyAudio also does not provide a meaningful error message (just says Python.h is missing).

Can I even have PyAudio be installed automatically without shipping my own wheel?
How do i provide helpful feedback to the user once the install fails?

Tried installing portaudio-devel which is available on my system but does not help.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `Python.h` means you need `python3-dev` (on Linux Ubuntu/Mint/Debian I installed it using `apt`, not `pip`)

Comment: All hail you kind sir @furas